# Filtering tweets based on hashtags and user_mentions

Tags: twitter, tweepy, twitter-streaming-api

I want to get realtime tweets using streaming api and then filter them based on a list of hashtags and user_mentions I have. Only those tweets should be fetched which has any hashtag among one of the items in the hashtags list or has a user_mention among one of the items in the user_mentions list.

I thought of first fetching all tweets and then while reading those, I would extract hashtags and user_mentions field and see if there is an intersection between that set and the one I have. The problem is how to get all the tweets.
 What should be specified as track parameter in stream.filter(). 
 Or is there a neater way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

If you **have** sets of hashtags and user mentions, you can track those directly.

```
# Lets say I have a user_mentions list...
user_mentions = ['@this_guy', '@that_guy', '@those_guys']

# And a hashtags list...
hashtags = ['#ThisHastag', '#ThatHashtag']

# You can merge them into one list of terms to be tracked
track_terms = user_mentions + hashtags

# The list "track_terms" now looks like this:
# track_terms = ['@this_guy', '@that_guy', '@those_guys', '#ThisHastag', '#ThatHashtag']

# Passing these to .filter() will collect tweets containing those terms
stream.filter(track=track_terms)
```

Comment: What if you wanted to filter a stream by hashtag ***and*** tweets by users with more than x followers? So only tweets from well followed users would show up in the hashtag stream.

Comment: Sure, my answer doesn't cover that because it wasn't the question asked. Of course its doable  - you're only limited by the limitations of the API itself. Thats a much more complex question than the one proposed here so I'm not sure its fair flesh that out in the comments (if you're actually asking how to do it) **or** to judge my answer by your proposed condition (if you're the one who downvoted me).

Comment: Oh no I wasn't the one who down voted, i just found this last night through google and had a question about pushing your answer a bit further. (I was simply being lazy instead of just opening a question myself.)

Comment: I can send you in the right direction for now - Tweets come in as JSON. Within that JSON, there are many fields describing aspects of the tweet (text, created_at, id, etc.). One of those fields is "user", and within that user section is a "followers_count" entry. See [these docs](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets) and scroll down to the "user" field. You can use that info to help filter the tweets you receive. If you need more help I'll be keeping and eye on the Tweepy tag and would be happy to give you a more structured answer if you feel like opening a question. Good luck!